# problem parsing INI section using Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm studying parsers for a college project. I found out about Boost.Spirit and decided to use it. After reading its documentation and implementing some basic examples, I tried to make a parser that parses a small INI section. The output of the program is:

#### Program error

```
<section>
  <try>[Section]\nkey1 = val</try>
  <key>
    <try>Section]\nkey1 = valu</try>
    <success>]\nkey1 = value1\nkey2</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </key>
  <fail/>
</section>

--------------------
Parsing failed
--------------------
```

#### Code

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace client 
{
    namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct ini_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ascii::space_type>
    {
        ini_grammar() : ini_grammar::base_type(section)
        {
            using qi::char_;
           
            key     = +char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
            pair    = key >> '=' >> key;
            section =
                '[' >> key  >> ']' 
                >> '\n'
                >> *(pair >> '\n')
                ;
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((key)(pair)(section))
        }

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> section, pair, key;
    };
}


int main() 
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::space;

    string ini_section =
        "[Section]\n"
        "key1 = value1\n"
        "key2 = value2\n";

    typedef client::ini_grammar<string::const_iterator> ini_grammar;
    ini_grammar grammar;
    
    string::const_iterator iter = ini_section.begin();
    string::const_iterator end  = ini_section.end();

    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, space);

    if (r == true) 
    {
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
        cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
        cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some context, I read this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120647/learning-boost-spirit-parsing-ini). I used the code provided on the question as a reference and try to use some of the hints provided on the answers.

Comment: Please don't post texts on images. Post a formatted text as a text in a code block like you have done it for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Key should not use a skipper. It is a "lexeme".

Next up, `'\n'` can never be matched as your skipper already eats it.

See [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Since you intend blank space to be insignificant in those rules, but NOT newlines, use `qi::blank`, not `qi::space`. Also, match `qi::eol` for more portability (DOS/UNIX line ends).
For finishing touches, accept multiple line ends if blank/empty lines are accepted.

While you're at it, don't expose the choice of skipper as it's essential to your grammar.

I've also elected to use `qi::space`/`qi::blank` for consistency with `qi::char_`.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e879a585d285f6d1)**

```cpp
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace client {
    template <typename Iterator> struct ini_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
        ini_grammar() : ini_grammar::base_type(start) {
            key     = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
            pair    = key >> '=' >> key;
            section = '[' >> key >> ']' >> +qi::eol >> *(pair >> +qi::eol);

            start   = qi::skip(qi::blank)[section];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((key)(pair)(section))
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator>                 start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::blank_type> section, pair;
        qi::rule<Iterator>                 key;
    };
} // namespace client

int main() {
    std::string const ini_section = R"([Section]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
)";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    client::ini_grammar<It> grammar;

    It iter = ini_section.begin(), end = ini_section.end();
    bool r = parse(iter, end, grammar);

    if (r == true) {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
```

### BONUS

With actual attribute propagation into datastructure:

```
using Key     = std::string;
using Value   = std::string;
using Section = std::map<Key, Value>;
using IniFile = std::multimap<Key, Section>;
```

And a better value rule that doesn't disallow spaces and other special characters.

And using a custom skipper to also ignore comments.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d962e6116a363d6)**

```cpp
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using Key     = std::string;
using Value   = std::string;
using Section = std::map<Key, Value>;
using IniFile = std::multimap<Key, Section>;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace client {
    template <typename Iterator> struct ini_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, IniFile()> {
        ini_grammar() : ini_grammar::base_type(start) {
            skipper = qi::blank | '#' >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol);

            key     = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
            value   = *(qi::char_ - qi::eol);
            pair    = key >> '=' >> value;
            section = '[' >> key >> ']' >> +qi::eol >> *(pair >> +qi::eol);
            file    = *section;

            start   = qi::skip(copy(skipper))[file];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((key)(value)(pair)(section)(file))
        }

      private:
        using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;
        Skipper skipper; // also skip comments

        using KVP = std::pair<Key, Value>;
        using SEC = std::pair<Key, Section>;
        qi::rule<Iterator, IniFile()>          start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, IniFile(), Skipper> file;
        qi::rule<Iterator, SEC(), Skipper>     section;
        qi::rule<Iterator, KVP(), Skipper>     pair;
        // lexemes
        qi::rule<Iterator, Key()>   key;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Value()> value;
    };
} // namespace client

int main() {
    std::string const ini_section = R"([First]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[otherSection]
key3 = It should really not matter how much spaces are included 
key4 = Or equal signs ("=") for that matter

# comments should be comments
# just like empty/blank lines
    
[First] #second first, actually
key5 = More
)";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    client::ini_grammar<It> section;

    It iter = ini_section.begin(), end = ini_section.end();
    IniFile ini;
    bool r = parse(iter, end, section, ini);

    if (r == true) {
        for (auto& [name,entries] : ini) {
            std::cout << "Section " << quoted(name) << "\n";
            for (auto& [k, v] : entries)
                std::cout << "\t" << quoted(k) << " -> " << quoted(v) << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Section "First"
    "key1" -> "value1"
    "key2" -> "value2"
Section "First"
    "key5" -> "More"
Section "otherSection"
    "key3" -> "It should really not matter how much spaces are included "
    "key4" -> "Or equal signs (\"=\") for that matter"
```

### Further examples

To have a flavor of INI file that expects quoted strings with optional escape characters instead of just accepting "bare strings" like the above:

- [Cross-platform way to get line number of an INI file where given option was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427)
- [How to make my split work only on one real line and be capable to skip quoted parts of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skip-quoted-pa/7462539#7462539) (actually about CSV, but quoted strings still apply)

Comment: In your first example, parsing is successful, but if I provide something like:

[section]
key1 value1

it still parses correctly. How would I create a grammar that does not accept keys that are not assigned to any value?

Comment: What do you define as "parse correctly"? I don't think it does:  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35ce5f4a89e4bde3 (note that I inspect the outcome more carefully than just going: "ok is true"). For what it's worth, if consuming all input is required for a parse to be "successful", just include `qi::eoi` in the parser: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7eb89b14e80261e (or indeed in my bonus example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d844071b68388545

Comment: By the way, if you're going to think of edge-cases, not only did my bonus section already deal with quite a few of those (that you didn't object about :)) you should probably also make sure that the last line may end without newline: test case https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55c4a4ce55395000 which I'd fix like e.g. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ce9ed318a6dc57. Summarizing: know your requirements and always have tests.